# Replicate SQL query with pivot structure from one table to another

Tags: sql-server

I am a SQL beginner trying to replicate the same SQL query below in the TABLE_2 like already implemented in TABLE_1 that ran successfully.

Basically the main difference between the two tables is that TABLE_1 contains two columns 'year_dt_emission' that contains year format reference like "2021" and another one called 'month_dt_emission' that contains months format reference like 1,2,3 till 12.

But TABLE_2 contains 'dt_emission' column with date format like YYYY-MM-DD that already contains year and month embedded that I would need.

Tables with columns reference:

- SERVER DB TABLE_1 w/ columns names --> year_dt_emission, month_dt_emission , customer_id, brand_name
- SERVER DB TABLE_2 w/ columns names --> dt_emission, customer_id, brand_name

I already tried to use function like YEAR and MONTH to capture/ convert the year number and month number respectively, but with no successfully.

The below code is the original one applied in the TABLE_1. Can someone help and guide me with appropriated query to fix and use TABLE_2 reference?

```
select brand_name
           , year_dt_emission
           , month_dt_emission as month_order
           , case month_dt_emission
           when 1 then 'Jan'when 2  then 'Feb'when 3  then 'Mar'when 4  then 'Apr'when 5  then 'May'when 6  then 'Jun'
           when 7  then 'Jul'when 8  then 'Aug'when 9  then 'Set'when 10 then  'Oct'when 11 then  'Nov'when 12 then  'Dec'
           end as month_dt_emission
           , [1] as 'Jan', [2] as 'Feb', [3] as 'Mar', [4] as 'Apr', [5] as 'May', [6] as 'Jun'
           , [7] as 'Jul', [8] as 'Aug', [9] as 'Set', [10] as 'Oct', [11] as 'Nov', [12] as 'Dec'
            
            from (
          select c.brand_name
                 , j_month.Joining_month
                 , c.month_dt_emission
                 , c.year_dt_emission
                 , count (distinct c.invoice_number) customer_id
                from   TABLE_1 c

          left  join (
                select year_dt_emission, brand_name, customer_id, min(month_dt_emission) Joining_month
                from   TABLE_1
                where  1=1
                group by year_dt_emission, brand_name, customer_id) j_month

          on (c.customer_id = j_month.customer_id and c.brand_name = j_month.brand_name and c.year_dt_emission = j_month.year_dt_emission)
          left join  (
                select year_dt_emission, brand_name, customer_id, count(distinct month_dt_emission) Months_Active
                from   TABLE_1
                where  1=1
                        
                group by year_dt_emission, brand_name, customer_id) m_month
                
          on (c.customer_id = m_month.customer_id and c.brand_name = m_month.brand_name and c.year_dt_emission = m_month.year_dt_emission)
          where 1=1
          and (m_month.Months_Active > 0 or j_month.Joining_month > 0)
                  
          group by c.brand_name
                 , j_month.Joining_month
                 , c.month_dt_emission
                 , c.year_dt_emission
                
          ) a
      PIVOT 
      (
      sum(customer_id) FOR Joining_month IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10],[11],[12])
      ) AS tbpivot
´´´
```

Answer (score 1):

Aim for a [minimal, reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when asking questions. We cannot run your query without table definitions and sample data. This makes it harder to validate/achieve the expected result and solution. Those `where 1=1` clauses seem unnecessary as well.

A [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) (CTE) would be one solution to transform the data before the pivoting.

**Sample data**

```
-- separate columns for year and month
create table table_1
(
  dt_year int,
  dt_month int,
  value int
);

insert into table_1 (dt_year, dt_month, value) values
(2021, 1, 100),
(2021, 1, 100),
(2021, 2, 50),
(2021, 2, 200),
(2021, 3, 70),
(2021, 4, 300),
(2022, 1, 50),
(2022, 3, 650);

-- no separate columns for year and month
create table table_2
(
  dt_full date,
  value int
);

insert into table_2 (dt_full, value) values
('2021-01-01', 100),
('2021-01-01', 100),
('2021-02-01', 50),
('2021-02-01', 200),
('2021-03-01', 70),
('2021-04-01', 300),
('2022-01-01', 50),
('2022-03-01', 650);
```

**Solution**

Base pivot query.

```
select piv.dt_year,
       piv.[1],
       piv.[2],
       piv.[3],
       piv.[4],
       piv.[5]
from table_1 t1
pivot (sum(t1.value) for t1.dt_month in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) piv;
```

Extended query with CTE to split the date field.

```
with cte as
(
  select year(t2.dt_full) as dt_year,
         month(t2.dt_full) as dt_month,
         t2.value
  from table_2 t2
)
select piv.dt_year,
       piv.[1],
       piv.[2],
       piv.[3],
       piv.[4],
       piv.[5]
from cte
pivot (sum(cte.value) for cte.dt_month in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) piv;
```

**Result**

Both sample tables contain the same values for each month, the output is therefore also the same.

```
dt_year  1     2     3     4      5
-------  ----  ----  ----  -----  ----
2021     200   250   70    300    null
2022     50    null  650   null   null
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=82dd10735f396deb5c8c60398d02f8cd) to see things in action.